# C# Switch case : which property is null?

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

I need to make a specific action depending which of my object's properties is null.

Is a switch case, that checks which property has been defined as "null", is possible ?

Something like this :

```
switch (Is Null)
{
        case "property1" : foo1()
        case "property2" : foo2()
        case "property3" : foo3()
        default : foo4()
}
```

Comment: i don't think that's possible in a non-hacky way. IMHO you should use if...elseif...else instead

Comment: if (p1 is null) then ... elseif (p2 is null) then ...

Comment: Or use reflection. Or rethink what you're doing. Why are you checking if the properties are null? There may be a far better way to do whatever you want

Comment: You want X. You don't have X but thought maybe “make a specific action depending which of my object's properties is null” would X. Now you discover that won't X. We can't help you until you [explain what X is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/135230).

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should: `new[]{ (x.Property1, (Action)foo1), (x.Property2, foo2), (x.Property3, foo3), (null, foo4) }.First(t => t.Item1 == null).Item2()`

Answer (score 6):

No, switch statements/expressions are about evaluating a single expression, then testing it against multiple values/patterns. It sounds like you want to evaluate multiple expressions, checking each against the same value (null).

Without knowing more details (like whether or not you'd actually want to execute multiple methods if multiple properties are null) it's hard to recommend a specific pattern, but `switch` almost certainly isn't a good fit.

It's just *possible* that pattern matching would actually allow this:

```cs
switch (x)
{
    case MyType { Property1: null }:
        Foo1();
        break;
    case MyType { Property2: null }:
        Foo2();
        break;
    // ...
}
```

... but that's so far from idiomatic C# that I really wouldn't do it.

Answer (score -3):

You are able to use a switch case for checking null values, but it would have to be on each individual property, but for a switch statement you can do:

```cs
switch(property1)
{
    case null:
        //do something
        break;
    default:
        //something else
        break;
}
```

Comment: although this _technically_ works, it's not something i'd _ever_ want to see in any codebase, except a demonstration of antipatterns.

Comment: It also suffers the problem of only being able to test one property. Another `switch` would be needed for each additional property. A basic `if`/`else if` sequence would be less to write and much easier to understand.